# Press S to skip mounting error after windows 8.1 installation

Tags: boot, mount, windows-8, ntfs, fstab

I have ubuntu 13.10 and I have just installed windows 8.1 on another drive.
After that I restarted to ubuntu and I had to press S twice in order to enter.
When I clicked on my Drives "Dati" and "Volume" from my file manager I could not access to them and I got the following error:

```
[mntent]: invalid line 9 in /etc/fstab
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operazione non permessa
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb3': Operazione non permessa
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Here is my **/etc/fstab**: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k3jyVay6

Here is the output of: `sudo blkid`: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QQggQfJx

How can I solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply caused by Windows 8 shutdown method that similliar to Hibernate or Sleep,you can simply run `shutdown -s -t 0` on Windows to shut it down completely, or you can disable *Fast Startup* function on Windows

Comment: and will it solve the mounting problems during boot?